# Authenticating a server using kerberos

Tags: java, windows, kerberos

I thought it could be a good idea to use kerberos on Windows 2003 to authenticate a Java server application against active directory. That way, we will not have to put a password in a file. But this does not work.

```
[2012-09-20 17:42:19,301] ERROR Cannot authenticate server via JAAS
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for KerberosLogin
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:273)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:349)
```

If I run the exact same code and configuration on Windows XP, then authentication works. In both cases I am using Java 7 u07.

Comment: could you throw some light on how you configured your application to use kerberos to authenticate with Windows AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my TGT that I had aquired via JDK's kinit command had expired.